# SIM7600e-h-4g is unable to connect to internet at initial startup, after the system is not used for approximately 2 months

Tags: networking, boot-issues

I'm very new to raspi world and am encountering the following problem. I had a raspiZero connecting to SIM7600e-h-4g (with a 4G SIM card) and connected to a physical switch to power on/off raspiZero and 2 LEDs bulbs (1st LED will show green if raspi has successfully started up and my App is running, the 2nd LED will show green if it is connected to internet, else red for error). I had a Python application (App) inside this raspiZero with a script to autorun this App whenever the system boots up. This App involves in information collection and sends collected data to the backend server via 4G.

The above works well. BUT if the system is not power up for more than 1 month, the system is unable to connect to internet after boot up. Meaning 1st LED showed green and 2nd LED showed red. Then when I run the APP manually using Geany (within the raspizero Linux environment), the system can then connect to the internet (all LEDs green). And thereafter, by switching off/on the system, it all works well again. When the system is again left untouched and not powered up for more than 1 month, the same problem pattern will happen again.

Can anyone guide me on how to troubleshoot this issue or have a solution to the problem?

Thanks & Regards,
JesC

Comment: the issue is likely with your APP. you should add some debugging output to your APP so you can see where it is failing.

Comment: The entire system + App is working well as long as every day the system is powered up at least 1 time. Working well here means App is able to connect to the internet. Not working well here means App is unable to connect to the internet with an error log stating 'unable to connect to internet' but other functionalities/algo in App are working fine.
In summary, it is just the 4G module portion having issue IF the system is not powered up for continuously of more than 1 month.

Comment: I wonder if the 4G module takes longer to connect if it hasn't been powered up for longer than a month, i.e. some delay due to your mobile data provider

Comment: I doubt is dued to mobile operator. Maybe related to one of the following reasons: 
1) once successfully running (raspi + SIM7600e-h-4g), it will continue to be successful irregardless of how many times I power on/off, as long as i power on at least once per day. Is there a cache memory within raspi?
2) Or time for SIM7600e-h-4g to be initialised is insufficient after prolonged inactivity?

** I'm using this website to build my system: (https://www.elementzonline.com/blog/accessing-internet-(jio-sim)-in-sim7600-4g-modem-v2.0-with-Raspberry-pi-using-qmi-interface)

Comment: so, the thing that makes it unreliable is NOT connecting the 4G to your mobile operator for an extended period of time, and you say you doubt it's the mobile operator? ... *Or time for SIM7600e-h-4g to be initialised is insufficient after prolonged inactivity* why? does the device have a memory of how long it's been inactive? (by inactive, I mean switched off)

Comment: One thing I would try ... delay your APP from starting for 30 to 60 seconds, that way the network has more chance of actually being established

Comment: Will definitely try to add delay to start the App. Thanks.